# how can I get the token instead of string?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have following syntax:

```
kv = Word(alphanums + '_') | QuotedString('"', escQuote="\\") | QuotedString("'", escQuote="\\")
kv = kv.setResultsName('literal', listAllMatches=True)
cskv = kv + Optional(ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + kv))  # comma separated kv
```

and with this example:

```
>>> res=cskv.parseString('a,b,c,d,e')
>>> res
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], {'literal': [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4)]})
>>> res[0]
'a'
>>> type(res[0])
<type 'str'>
```

notice:

```
>>> type(res[0])
<type 'str'>
```

i really actually want it to be `ParseResults`, instead of string, such that i can `res[0].getName()` to it, and hopefully i should get `literal`.

the second question is how can I get the index of some token?

let's say i want to know the index of `literal d`, it should return `3`.

it's trivial in this example since i have only one type of token, but in my problem, i need to know the relative position of different types of tokens so that it will help while processing.

any way to achieve these?

### EDIT:

i don't know why my question is so confusing and why people keep focusing on my example instead of my question. following is more clarification:

i use pyparsing as a tokenizer, to tokenize a string to interprete it, the problem i have, is i need to know what that token is, let's say (which means it's a made up not-worthy-focusing-on illustration):

```
variable = string
```

if some language support this, and it knows when a string happens to be a left value then it's a variable, if it's right value it will be a string(don't ask me why is that, it's made up).

so i am expecting this syntax:

```
expr = Word(alphanums+'_')('leftval') + '=' + Word(alphanums+'_')('rightval')
```

at the end, that expression should be perfectly tokenized:

```
In [3]: res = expr.parseString('variable = string')

In [4]: res
Out[4]: (['variable', '=', 'string'], {'rightval': [('string', 2)], 'leftval': [('variable', 0)]})
```

but this is my question:

```
In [5]: res[0]
Out[5]: 'variable'

In [6]: type(res[0])
Out[6]: str
```

now `res` gives a string to me. i need a tokenizer to work, including the information following with the token, now i lost the token's name, which should be `leftval`.

funny enough, the `__repr__` of `res` has shown all info i need:

the token names, and in all of them, the captured tokens themselves as well as there position in the tokenizing result `res`.

see that?

this is exactly my question. not how to deal with comma separate values with pyparsing.

Comment: Why do you need to implement a csv parser using pyparsing?

Comment: it's totally pissing me off. why should i invent a whole big example just to illustrate my problem? what's wrong with my question? why is it worth a downvote? SO will be vanished one day because of all these nonsense.

Comment: I agree that parsing a csv with pyparsing is crazy.... but even more I agree that this is a perfectly valid question and I dont get why it was downvote... I also dont think telling him to use csv module is a valid answer... his question is how to get the TOKEN_NAME instead of the value

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia i am not parsing a csv. it's just a illustration of the question.

Comment: upvoted to offset downvotes ...

Comment: keep calm and carry on :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's simply because some people just feel like playing god. they take a glance with out reading more than 10 words and make judgement.

Comment: @MichaelJaros thanks. i plan to use pyparsing for something absolutely else and start to learn it today but got stuck in this problem for the whole afternoon. terrible day.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Sorry for our misunderstanding. I hope that my answer will help you!

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it's not a good idea to rant in your question.  That's a good way to actually get the post downvoted or flagged.

Comment: @JAL you may be right but i don't think i can bear with this. i rarely ask a question in SO. most of time, i answer or answer in the comment. and when it comes to my turn to ask, i got this. what those people do insulted me too much + today i was in very bad mood.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the issues raised in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282878/distinguish-matches-in-pyparsing  The user wrapped the strings in a Group to get them as a ParseResults, which then supported getName().  My answer to this question also provides a couple of other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas,alphanums,QuotedString,Optional,ZeroOrMore,Suppress

kv = Word(alphanums + '_') | QuotedString('"', escQuote="\\") | QuotedString("'", escQuote="\\")
kv = kv.setResultsName('literal', listAllMatches=True)
cskv = kv + Optional(ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + kv))  # comma separated kv
tokens = cskv.parseString("a,b,c,d,e")

#you can use asDict to get a dictionary mapping names to values
print tokens.asDict()

#or you can get it as xml and parse the xml
import re
xml_result = tokens.asXML()
for tok in tokens:
    needle = "\<([^\>]+)\>\s*%s\s*\<\/"%tok
    print tok, "=", re.search(needle,xml_result).groups()[0]
```

there may be a better way to do this ... Im not sure ... it also may break with more complex grammars ...

based on your comments try

```
import ast
parsed_values,meta_data = ast.literal_eval(repr(tokens))
print parsed_values # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print meta_data # {'literal': [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4)]}
```

Comment: it seems more complicated than i think. notice that the repr of the result has information in the second field. i am wondering if there is some sort of interfaces can extract that out.

Comment: just parse the xml with lxml and you should get all the info you want ... @HuStmpHrrr ok I think i made it do what you want

Answer (score 0):

According to the pyparsing documentation exists the *delimitedList* function that it's used in order to parse specific string composed by multiple characters delimited by a specific separator.

I'll quote it:

> Helper to define a delimited list of expressions - the delimiter defaults to ','. By default, the list elements and delimiters can have intervening whitespace, and comments, but this can be overridden by passing combine=True in the constructor. If combine is set to True, the matching tokens are returned as a single token string, with the delimiters included; otherwise, the matching tokens are returned as a list of tokens, with the delimiters suppressed.

Now you just need to use it and parse a string using it to get a *ParseResult* object:

```
csvExpr = delimitedList()

parsed = csvExpr.parseString("a,b,c,d,e")

print(type(parsed)) # output: <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
```

Comment: this isn't really answering his question ... this yields the same results as his grammar (although you rightly point out there is a type already in place for a delimited list)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Doesn't he want a ParseResults object? It's still not clear what he want to obtain...

Comment: he wants to know the name of the token (in his case it is "literal" (ofc since that is the only token))